# Why can't I uninstall Photoshop CC without also uninstalling Photoshop CC 2014?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, uninstall

I have both Photoshop CC and Photoshop CC 2014 installed on my computer.

I'd like to uninstall Photoshop CC, but running the uninstall itself brings up both CC and CC 2014, with Photoshop CC greyed out:

[image: Uninstall screenshot]

Is it possible to uninstall CC without also uninstalling 2014?

Comment: Because Adobe designed their installer to do this.  If I were to make an educated guess there are shared components between the two versions.

Comment: @Ramhound No, there are in fact two versions: CC and CC 2014. Adobe has majorly screwed up the uninstall process; I remember having had the same issue on OS X.

Comment: @slhck - I could have sworn that this was their "cloud" version of Photoshop. But I also revised my statement.

Comment: @Ramhound They recently released an updated version of their cloud software, and decided to distribute it as "CC 2014" alongside the existing "CC" line. It's all a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can! That's not CC and CC 2014, that's **CC 32 bit and CC 64 bit**. CC 2014 was the [first release](http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2014/06/2014-release-of-photoshop-cc-separate-32-bit64-bit-installation.html) to have a separate 32-bit and 64-bit installation.

> In order to optimize download and install time, we no longer package both the 64-bit and 32bit version in the same installer.

Here's what the uninstallers look like for CC, CC 2014, and CC 2015:

[image: Photoshop CC Uninstaller]
[image: Photoshop CC 2014 Uninstaller]
[image: Photoshop CC 2015 Uninstaller]